# AngularJS custom on change not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a simple code that is invoked on choosing a file to read through it and popluate a select box with options

The Angular Code -

```
angapp.controller('panbulkCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.deviceGroups = [];
    $scope.uploadFile = function() {
        var filename = event.target.files[0].name;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var cells = rows[i].split(",");
                for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                    console.log(cells[j]);
                    $scope.deviceGroups.push(cells[j]);
                }              
            }           
        }
        reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
    }
});

angapp.directive('customOnChange', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var onChangeFunc = scope.$eval(attrs.customOnChange);
            element.bind('change', onChangeFunc);
        }
    };
});
```

The HTML Template

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-color:white">
</div>
<div class="jumbotron container-fluid">
<h3 align="center">PAN Bulk Upload</h3>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-9">
<div style="border-right:1px solid #cbc6c6">
<div class="container panel-body">
    <label class="custom-file-upload">
        <input id="fileChoose" type="file" custom-on-change="uploadFile" />
        <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"> Choose Device Group File</i>
    </label>
    <hr/>
    <select size=5 style="width:200px;height:100px" ng-model="deviceGroupsList" ng-options="o as o for o in deviceGroups">
    </select>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <button ng-click="validateDeviceGroups()">Validate</button>
    <button ng-click="commitDeviceGroups()">Commit</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
<textarea rows="20" cols="35"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The uploadFile function reads through and appends to the array the lines of the file. But it isnt rendered properly on the select box until some other button is clicked. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run a digest loop manually. Because `reader.onload` function is out of angular world. Angular doesn't track changes inside it. So you need to make angular know that something has changed outside the scope of it. And Angular needs to update those changes in the UI.

To do that use:

> `$scope.$apply()`

after it appends to the array the lines of the file.

**So, your controller code should look like:**

```
angapp.controller('panbulkCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.deviceGroups = [];
    $scope.uploadFile = function() {
        var filename = event.target.files[0].name;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var cells = rows[i].split(",");
                for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                    console.log(cells[j]);
                    $scope.deviceGroups.push(cells[j]);
                }              
            }
            $scope.$apply()           
        }
        reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
    }
});
```